# Gnuplot produces an empty diagram

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to plot a simple diagram with gnuplot. Unfortunately it's not drawing anything. The ranges on the diagram are correct.

This are my commands:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
plot 'output-small.dat' using 1:3 with points
```

Contents of `output-small.dat`:

```
#ErfassungsZeit         VerbrauchT
2013-05-15 10:15:21.187 186.209729771549
2013-05-15 10:14:20.933 224.545927174927
2013-05-15 10:13:20.537 188.126047613839
....
2013-05-15 09:54:15.707 254.789197859055
2013-05-15 09:53:15.580 213.93299371326
2013-05-15 09:52:15.547 280.716197626502
```

And this ist he resulting diagram:
[image]

Any idea what's missing?

Comment: Your script works without modification here, Gnuplot version 4.6 patchlevel 3.

Comment: Same here. Maybe some problem with the terminal?

Comment: I'm on windows. Does this matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just started the very same script today and everything is fine. Thanks for the support anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the terminal, e.g.

```
set terminal wxt
```

or download the latest version of gnuplot.
With that version and png terminal, your script works: http://www.plotshare.com/index.ws/plot/783099223

Comment: If you are working interactively, try adding a "reset" to the script because sometimes strange settings interfere with the plots.